SwiftUI Color in Light/Dark Mode Doesn't Update in Preview or Simulator
I'm working on a SwiftUI test project that involves adjusting colours based on light and dark mode settings.
In my asset catalog, I've configured theme.colorset to support different colours for light and dark environments, allowing me to test how colours adapt to each mode.

However, I'm experiencing an issue where my code seems to only pick up the .light mode colour, regardless of the environment. This problem occurs in the preview canvas, simulator, and even on a physical device when launched in dark mode.
I initially thought this could be a caching issue, but clearing the cache hasn’t resolved it.

Here's a minimal example of the code I'm working with:
struct ContentView: View {
    private var baseColor: Color = .theme
    var body: some View {
        LuminanceVStack(baseColor: baseColor, incrementPercentage: 5)
    }
}

struct LuminanceVStack: View {
    var baseColor: Color
    var incrementPercentage: Double

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            let stepCount = Int(100.0 / incrementPercentage) + 1

            ForEach(0..<stepCount, id: \.self) { i in
                let luminance = Double(i) * (incrementPercentage / 100.0)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(adjustLuminance(baseColor: baseColor, luminance: luminance))
            }
        }
    }

    private func adjustLuminance(baseColor: Color, luminance: Double) -> Color {
        let uiColor = UIColor(baseColor)

        var hue: CGFloat = 0
        var saturation: CGFloat = 0
        var brightness: CGFloat = 0
        var opacity: CGFloat = 0

        uiColor.getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &opacity)

        return Color(
            uiColor: UIColor(
                hue: hue,
                saturation: saturation,
                brightness: max(min(luminance, 1.0), 0.0),
                alpha: opacity
            )
        )
    }
}

Demo video of simulator changing environment but colour not updating
What I've Tried

Preview Reset: Tried resetting the canvas preview, thinking it might be a caching issue.
Simulator: Tested in the simulator by explicitly setting the environment to dark mode, but still only the light mode colours appear.
Physical Device: Tested on a physical device in dark mode, and it still only applies the light mode colour.

Question
Why does the environment’s light/dark setting seem to be ignored, and is there a way to ensure the colours adjust according to the active mode? Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot or approach this would be appreciated.

Your problem arises when you call getHue on the UIColor - It seems that this function doesn't respect dynamic colours and you always get the values from the light variant.
If you change adjustLuminance to simply return Color(uiColor:uiColor) instead of returning the new UIColor created from the hue/saturation then it works as expected (although without the variations).
I would suggest you see if you can find SwiftUI modifiers such as saturation or brightness to meet your needs rather than trying to use UI Kit.
For example:
Rectangle().fill(baseColor).brightness(-(1-luminance)) looks like it gives your desired output


